# Adding a paragraph to PDF with specific coordinates size

Tags: python, pdf, formatting, pypdf

I am using python for modifying PDFs but I have a PDF template which I am trying to automatize. I am using PyPDF2 and reportlab to do so. For single sentences I am using the reportlab's drawString function.
However I'd like to now create and paste a paragraph to the specific coordinates on the first page. I know that the paragraph should be bounded on the left side by 2cm on the right side by 2cm and should start 10 cm from the top. The bottom is not specified and limited as the paragraph length is not known upfront.

How can I achieve this using reportlab and PyPDF2?

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf